# Custom metric access X input data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics

I'd like to write a custom metric for a spelling correction model that counts correctly substituted letters that were previously incorrect. And it should be counted incorrectly substituted letters that were previously correct.

That's why I need access to the x_input data. Unfortunately, only y_true and y_pred are accessible by default. Is there a workaround to get to the matching x_input?

Is:

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
```

Wanted:

```
def custom_metric(x_input, y_true, y_pred):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def custom_loss(x_input):
    def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
        # Use your x_input here directly
        return #Your loss value
    return loss_fn

model = # Define your model
model.compile(loss=custom_loss(x_input))   
# Values of y_true and y_pred will be passed implicitly by Keras
```

Remember that `x_input` will be having same values across all batches of input while model is getting trained.

**EDIT**:

Since you need `x_input` data **only** of every batch for estimating during the loss function and you are having your own custom loss function, why don't you pass the `x_input` as labels. Something like this:

```
model.fit(x=x_input, y=x_input)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss())

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  # y_true corresponds to x_input data
```

If you need x_input and you need to pass some other data, you can do like this:

```
model.fit(x=x_input, y=[x_input, other_data])
model.compile(loss=custom_loss())
```

You just need to decouple the data in `y_true` now.

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted out. Suppose I train with 10,000 samples and a batch size of 128. Then, as far as I understand y_true and y_pred would have a shape size of e.g. (128, 28, 28). The x_input would have a shape size of (10,000, 28, 28) with your variant and does not correspond to the section, which I would need.